# Make an animation with the Glorious JavaScript library

Tags: javascript, animation, webstorm

I have been trying to use the library to make material for my students.

https://glorious.codes/demo

I want to make animations, but I cannot understand how to use or where to use the library. I think it is necessary to use it from an html file. install the library but when opening the page it only creates the text that I place as a test.

I am using WebStorm as IDE, creating a node.js project.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/@glorious/demo/dist/gdemo.min.css">
    <script src="node_modules/@glorious/demo/dist/gdemo.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Can someone guide me on what program or how to work with the library. It is the first time that I try to perform animation with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are new to web technologies, there is a pretty steep curve here.  Personally, I'd take a step back and familiarize myself with the tools.  If you have a minute, check out [W3school](https://www.w3schools.com/)'s site.  There is plenty of information to get you moving quickly with HTML/CSS/JS.  Specifically focus on [CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) and [Javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_intro.asp) and this will make a lot more sense.

Now for the question you asked:

First, NodeJS isn't necessarily required to achieve your goal.  You can create a simple HTML file and reference the Glorious libraries directly from the web.  See what I did in the `<script>` and `<link>` elements below.

Once you have the libraries loaded, you need to:

1. Instantiate the library and assign it to a variable to use in the future (see `const demo = new GDemo(...)`)
2. Tell the library where in your HTML you want it to render the animation.  In this case it is a `<div/>` with `id='container'`.
3. Tell the library what to render.  This is the `gDemo.openApp(...)` section.  I pulled this example directly from this library's [GitHub](https://github.com/glorious-codes/glorious-demo) page.

```js
const gdemo = new GDemo('#container');

const code = 'console.log("Hello World!");'


gdemo
  .openApp('editor', {
    minHeight: '400px',
    windowTitle: 'demo.js'
  })
  .write(code, {
    onCompleteDelay: 2000
  })
  .openApp('terminal', {
    minHeight: '400px',
    promptString: '$'
  })
  .command('node ./demo')
  .respond('Hello World!')
  .command('')
  .end();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@glorious/demo/dist/gdemo.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@glorious/demo/dist/gdemo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, I already managed to show the animation. But I don't know if I'm fine the way I do it, use the second code that you show me and add a script tag with the first code of your answer. this way when loading the page it shows me the result. My question: Is this the correct way? or do you need two files? or where in the HTML file the first code goes. Thanks for answering. I have never programmed with HMTL and javascript and I did not know where to start or how to explain.

Comment: Great! Glad it is working.  What you have proposed is completely acceptable at a small scale -- especially if your task is to generate a few one-off animations.  If you'd like to separate your view from your javascript, you can absolutely reference in a script tag just as we did for "gdemo.min.js." Put a new `.js` file in the same folder as your `.html` file and reference by `<script src="fileName.js"/>`.  This should be in <head> but after gdemo library reference.

Comment: It only works by placing the script  `<script src="fileName.js"/>`  below the `<div>`. But thanks, this is more than enough for my work.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please detail a bit more the problem. From your example you just created an empty page. What are you trying to put in your page ? Tables ?

Also I would suggest the use of framework like Materials (https://material.io/components) within React if you are starting a Js project from scratch except if you have something specific in this lib you really want to display.

Comment: I don't know how to show the animation, I have never used html or javascript, I just need to know if some way to show or if I am using the correct format. I just want to create the animations and then export them to gif or video.

Comment: While React and materialui can help make beautiful responsive web applications, please be careful about recommending frameworks like this.  The question is very much about "why won't my animation render?"  Adding a complex UI framework and styling system will only add to the confusion.